# How to group a dataframe and then put two columns into one json like column in Python

Tags: python

The data i have is something similar to this:

| country | population | area | city | city_population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 331893745 | 9833520 | New York | 8804190 |
| USA | 331893745 | 9833520 | Los Angeles | 3898747 |
| USA | 331893745 | 9833520 | Chicago | 2746388 |
| UK | 243610 | 66366000 | London | 7556900 |
| UK | 243610 | 66366000 | Birmingham | 984333 |
| Canada | 9984670 | 38532853 | Toronto | 2600000 |
| Canada | 9984670 | 38532853 | Montreal | 1600000 |
| Canada | 9984670 | 38532853 | Calgary | 1019942 |

I am looking for output like this:

| country | population | area | cities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 331893745 | 9833520 | {'New York' : 8804190, 'Los Angeles' : 3898747, 'Chicago' : 2746388} |
| UK | 243610 | 66366000 | {'London' : 7556900, 'Birmingham' : 984333} |
| Canada | 9984670 | 38532853 | {'Toronto' : 2600000, 'Montreal' : 1600000, 'Calgary' : 1019942} |

So basically I want to group by the country column and then put city and city_population into a JSON-like column while keeping the other columns.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is pandas [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function, which creates groups depending on multiple columns with the same value. These groups can then be transformed with other functions based on your problem. In your case, I would apply a lambda function, which takes the `city` column and `city_population` and creates a dictionary (JSON-like structure). The next two statements are only to have a nice index and the correct column name.

```
(df.groupby(by=['country', 'population', 'area'])
    .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['city'], x['city_population'])))
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0:'Cities'}))
```

Output:

```
  country  population      area                                                             Cities
0  Canada     9984670  38532853      {'Toronto': 2600000, 'Montreal': 1600000, 'Calgary': 1019942}
1      UK      243610  66366000                          {'London': 7556900, 'Birmingham': 984333}
2     USA   331893745   9833520  {'New York': 8804190, 'Los Angeles': 3898747, 'Chicago': 2746388}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations! yes, the JSON like structure is just a dictionary.

Comment: Glad I could help!